# How to disable extension sharing via excludedActivityTypes?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiactivityviewcontroller, pinterest

I've built a sharing method using UIActivityViewController but I only want Airdrop, Twitter, Facebook, Messenger, and E-Mail to show up when one presses the share button. I've managed to disable paste board, print, copy, reading list, etc. but apps like pinterest won't work for what I'm doing. How would I disable sharing via extensions?

Answer (score 0):

That's currently not possible. You should file an [enhancement request with apple](https://bugreport.apple.com) explaining why this would be useful to the user/developer.

Comment: Thanks! I've actually figured out something that makes extensions work well.

Comment: Can you share what you found?